# How to indicate a bean with another bean?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have three beans:

```
<bean id="number" class="Number">

</bean>

<bean id="1" class="Number">
    <!--some property-->
</bean>

<bean id="2" class="Number">
    <!--some property-->
</bean>
```

I want to indicate id="number" bean to be id="1" just like :

```
<bean id="number" class="Number" ref="1">

</bean>
```

But it's failed.

How to implement the requirement?

Comment: I have no time for a complete answer but I think you should have a look at spring constructor args. With a `<constructor-arg value="1"/>` inside your <bean> node, you should be able to achieve what you want (given your bean constructor with 1 parameter exists of course)

Comment: You should add more details to your question as it's not clear what you want to achieve. From what I understand, you want to have one bean to be referenced two ids ("number" and "1"). You can use [aliases](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.20.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-beanname), like this:
 `<alias name="1" alias="number"/>`